# How do you insert an HTML block (with python) into a currently working website....?

Tags: python, html, substitution

Right now I have a solution that works from looking at some examples.  It looks like this

```
pagetemp = string.Template(open("index_template.html").read())
#print pagetemp.template

f = open("index.html","w")
f.write(pagetemp.substitute(sean_final_output=sean_final_output))
f.close()
return 1
```

sean_final_output is an html block of code, and I just use a $sean_final_output in that template... is there a more proper way to do this?  I.E. instead of having a 'template' file can I directly edit the index.html?  I guess the advantage is I can just do a substitute the way I am doing it now... I just feel like I am reading in one file and outputting to another so I dont' know if its the most efficient way.... (I want to learn the python way)

Comment: Are you open to doing this using bash? ;)

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? Do you want to serve an html file to a client? what framework are you using?

Comment: You should probably get used to reading one file and writing to another - it's generally the way you do things in programs. When you think you're 'editing'  a file, you're usually just reading it, then writing it back to disk again. You can 'append' to the end of a file on disk, but you can't just edit something in the middle.

Comment: @Jeune not really interested in bash.... the rest of the program is in python

Comment: @Simon uh this is supposed to just generate a report on an already generated html page.  Eventually I will also have a webpage where you can input which html file you want the report on, but right now you just run it on your local box...

Comment: @ThomasK thanks!  I am glad I am thinking the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is just fine, for a single simple replacement. However, if you're going to do anything more complex, this method will quickly become clumsy.

It is worth noting that there are quite a few existing solutions for creating text from templates, especially HTML. [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) and [Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/) are two examples of mature and widely used Python templating libraries, and there are several others as well. I highly recommend using one of these!